# mongodb websrv port

Tags: mongodb, port

By default, Mongodb runs on `27017` and `28017` ports (mongo itself and *http console*). I'm able to specify mongo port that will be used to listen database connections, using `--port` option and if I say

```
--port 1234
```

`websrv` port would be +1000:  `2234`.
Does anyone know how can i specify **both** server and http console ports?

for example:
*./mongod --port 8012 --websrvport 8022*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't look like that's possible unfortunately; the web-interface port is [hardcoded in the source](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/db/dbwebserver.cpp#L532) as `const int p = cmdLine.port + 1000;`